# Distributing consumers among suppliers without exceeding their capacity

Tags: algorithm

I am pretty sure this is a popular problem or a variation of one but my google skills failed me.

I have a set of suppliers and consumers. There is only a single resource type. Each supplier/consumer can have different capacity/consumption rates. I want to assign those consumers to suppliers in an optimized way. Here are the rules:

- A consumer can only be assigned to a single supplier. A supplier can have multiple consumers
- A consumer only has access to a subset of suppliers.
- A consumer can have a sub-optimal access to a supplier. In that case it will only get a percentage of the resources it asked.
- If a supplier has more consumers then it's capacity can handle, the supplier will only supply a percentage for all its consumers.

So given these conditions and a set of suppliers and consumers, I want to find out a list of assignments that will maximize percentages of the supply each consumer gets. Ideally everyone will get 100% of what they asked (no one is assigned using a sub-optimal access and all suppliers can fully support all their consumers). If there is no perfect solution, I guess it can optimize average percentage.

```
Example: 
Suppliers: 10 8
Consumers: 6 7 4

Solution for everyone has 100% to everything: 
6 and 4 is assigned to 10. 7 is assigned to 8. Everyone gets 100% of the supply it asked

7 has no access to 8: 
7 and 4 is assigned to 10. 6 is assigned to 8. Percentages for 6 7 4 is 100% ~91% ~91%. average is ~94%

6 has partial access to 10, can draw at most 4 resources: 
7 and 4 is assigned to 10. 6 is assigned to 8. Percentages for 6 7 4 is 100% ~91% ~91%. average is ~94%
(if we assign 6 and 4 to 10 and 7 to 8 then the percentages are ~66% 100% 100% (4/6 7/7 4/4) and average is ~88% and worse)
```

I have a greedy solution that exploits some problem specific information to find a solution but I know that it will fail to optimize in some cases.

Comment: This looks like the bin packing problem, there are only sub-optimal polynomial time solutions as it is NP-complete. One algorithm you could use is first fit.